# jQuery - load data to DIV when this div exist and visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want load HTML data to DIV. But… I create this DIV when page is loaded (I use tipped script to show "window" and load file with div #chat-conversation). I don't know why, but this code dont work:

```
if($('#chat-conversations').length){    
        if($('#chat-conversations').is(':visible')){
            $('#chat-conversations').load('/AJAX/Chat.app');
        }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error, what is the html like? Is the url correct?

Comment: have you tried using fiddler to check the requests? As Esa mentioned, is the url correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. When I try with another (exist on start) div, content is load.

Answer (score 0):

a couple of hint

1. is this code executed on $(document).ready ?
2. is #chat-conversation   present only once in your DOM ?
3. if you put a breakpoint on the 2nd line what does $("#chat-conversations")
   equals to?

code seems right, i think the problem is in the acutal DOM it is applied to

Comment: 1. Yes. When I change #chat-conversations to another div (exist on start) it's work.

Comment: can you post somewhere the page you're working on? i think ther's a problem with the HTML

Answer (score 0):

load allows you to specify a callback function you can use to check what is happening, for example:

```
$('#chat-conversations').load('/AJAX/Chat.app', function(html, status, xhr) {
  console.log(status);
});
```

If status is, for example, notfound you'll know your url is not correct.

[**Load's doc page**](https://api.jquery.com/load/)